# How to constrain an image to a guideline : Android constrained layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

My requirement is to place an image in a way that the half part of the image is above the horizontal guideline and another half is under the guideline(Exactly half). I have tried

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
```

it is working properly on some devices. 
my requirement will look like  this

[image]

but on some devices, it's not divided into halves. but the constraint is still satisfied

[image]

I have tried vertical bias and vertical weight but still, it's not working how can I fix this issue?

I think these constraints are still satisfied

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
```

is there any efficient way to achieve my requirement?

a portion of my XML

```
  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

        <com.cloud.appsteam.profile.HexagonMaskView
            android:id="@+id/iv_profile_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_img_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_img_height"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/neymar_dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline" />
```

Comment: Did you define your guideline using percentage ?

Comment: yes ,  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"

Comment: Please post your layout code

Comment: I think you should post your xml code so your question becomes more clear to us and we can observe the actual problem.

Comment: And did you try LayoutInspector to find out the problem https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html

Comment: You only need top and bottom margins -- no need for vertical bias here. If it works on some device and not on others that's another problem. Which version of ConstraintLayout are you using?

Comment: @Raghunandan   tried it, I can't find anything related to my issue

Comment: @NicolasRoard 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support multiple screen sizes then I think you have to do that **programmatically**.

Comment: How can I implement this  programmatically